# $ab-(a+b)(a-b)=0$ and the Golden ratio.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, golden-ratio

I have found:

$b=a*\phi$

$b=a*(-\phi)$

$b=a/\phi$

Trying to find the correlation with the equation and phi,
any insight how to demonstrate this or a proof?

Comment: that's pretty much the definition of the golden ratio plus some simple algebraic manipulation. what's your question?

Answer (score 3):

The golden ratio $\phi$ is usually defined to be the ratio of $a$ and $b$ as in this diagram:

[image]

where the red rectangle, with the proportions $\frac ab$, is similar to  the large rectangle with proportions $\frac{a+b}a$, so  $$\phi = \frac ab = \frac{a+b}{a}.$$

Multiplying on both sides by $ab$ we obtain $$a^2 = ab+b^2$$ so $$ab = a^2 - b^2 = (a+b)(a-b).$$